# Execute cmd from same directory with commands in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I have a folder named Scripts in which I have  files. Namely test.py and ffmpeg.exe 
Now, I want to write a code in test.py to execute this ffmpeg.exe in same directory with some arguments/commands.

I looked it up, but, only found how to execute cmd with arguments. I don't want to call cmd and then change directory and execute this command.

Any other way for this?

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.Popen` has an option of `cwd` to specify working directory.

```
import os
import subprocess

# Absolute path to directory of where this script is located
here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


subprocess.Popen("ffmpeg.exe", cwd=here)
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work. I might've done soemthing wrong. But, I got something similar working.

Answer (score 0):

Well,What I did with the code was get the directory first and do what casualdemon told me to do. This worked in the end :)

```
working_directory = os.getcwd()
p = subprocess.Popen(['my command here'], cwd=working_directory)
p.wait()
```